# how to force orientation mode in a particular view

Tags: angularjs, cordova, orientation

Doing an cordova app with angularjs as the frontend framework. I want a particular view in a phonegap/cordova app to appear in landscape mode. The various options I've explored so far are:

- Setting the [config.xml](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/config_ref_index.md.html). But you'd want this only if you intend the whole app to either be in portrait or landscape
- Adding [manifest.json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360699/145682). (Also taking care that I do not have any orientation settings defined in my config.xml). My plan was to conditionally include the file when I want to set my orientation as landscape.

So for the 2nd option I've written code in my pages such as:

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json" ng-if="orientation == 'landscape'">
```

...and in the controller toggling the value of `orientation` - with the intent of forcing it on demand.

However the above approach doesn't work.

Any idea on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about the angularjs part. But you can try/use [Orientationlock plugin](https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock) to dynamically lock and unlock the Orientation.

From the plugin description

From your JavaScript code call `window.plugins.orientationLock.unlock()` to unlock orientation, `window.plugins.orientationLock.lock("portrait")` or `window.plugins.orientationLock.lock("landscape")` to lock your screen to the specified orientation.

To start your Cordova application pre-locked place `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);` or `setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);` in the onCreate() of your Cordova activity.

Once unlocked, you can track orientation changes with the regular orientationchange event:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
   alert(window.orientation);
});
```

Comment: I think plugin's description is self explanatory. Anyway updated the answer.. :)