# Set landscape fixed on browser

Tags: angularjs, html, screen-orientation

I am making an webinterface for some device. But this interface is just supported landscape. Is it possible to set this fixed. Because when i turn it on my tablet it is just crap.

I am using for development Angular JS. 
I thought maybe with some viewport meta tag but im not sure

Comment: possible duplicate of [Blocking device rotation on mobile web pages](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3501510/blocking-device-rotation-on-mobile-web-pages)

Answer (score 0):

As from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086713/how-to-force-orientation-mode-in-a-particular-view), you can use [orientationlock](https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock) plugin to achieve this.

From your JavaScript code call

```
window.plugins.orientationLock.unlock()
```

to unlock orientation,

```
window.plugins.orientationLock.lock("landscape")
```

to lock your screen to landscape mode.

Once unlocked, you can track orientation changes with the regular orientationchange event:

```
window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function() {
   alert(window.orientation);
});
```

Other way is to use CSS and javascript :

```
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {

  #container {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    width: /* screen width */ ;
    height: /* screen height */ ;
    overflow: scroll;
  }
}
```

Comment: How does i use the screen orientation api in chrome?

Comment: Orientation is compatible in chrome 38. Check this out : http://www.sitepoint.com/screen-orientation-api-reloaded/    and   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen/lockOrientation#blink-note

Comment: I use chrome 42.0.2311.135  but when i do screen.orientation. I get undefined.

Comment: Add your efforts in the question. or add a fiddle to debug.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/WtKQNzeol8XGIZ4kqKh2 here you see when you inspect in the console