# How to set the orientation for required pages to landscape and other pages in portrait mode in phonegap application for both android and iOS

Tags: jquery, css, cordova, mobile, cordova-plugins

I am working on the enterprise apps which is dashboard application in phonegap for both android and iOS. In my app, 4 screens need to be developed on portrait mode and others should be in landscape. Here, I need to set the screen orientation portrait to portrait and landscape to landscape irrespective of sensor(without rotating the mobile). I have made a research for more than 3 days and not able to find out a correct plugin or correct piece of code. Already tried using -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg), but the screen is occupied with portrait size for landscape, therefore the screen is occupying extra space in 4 directions. Please suggest me any solution which will work definitely.

Comment: check out this cordova plugin https://github.com/cogitor/PhoneGap-OrientationLock

Answer (score 0):

Use @media tag (which I am less familiar with and only picked up on a few weeks ago). Two good articles on how this was done (read both completely as both have good answers)

[forcing web-site to show in landscape mode only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8738072/forcing-web-site-to-show-in-landscape-mode-only)

[Force “Landscape” orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode)