# Emulate orientation change without resizing browser window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it somehow possible to emulate page portrait orientation from PC browser, without resizing window?

In my HTML, I have `<div>`, which content changes dynamically depending on screen orientation. Can I create some JavaScript function to make this `<div>` "think" that screen is portrait right now, without using devtools and resizing windows?

Comment: found solution here, in edit of first answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode

Answer (score 1):

If you'll go to developer tools in chrome (F12) you can run mobile device emulator. You can choose which device you'd like to emulate or create your own configuration. Additionally there is one-click screen orientation changer.

Comment: yup, and I've told that I wanted to perform the same action without going in developer tools. Thank you anyway