# Rotate mobile screen with jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

How to change the mobile orientation of mobile screen on the click of button? Like portrait view to landscape view?

Comment: Look this: http://www.noupe.com/design/html5-screen-orientation-api-uses-javascript-to-rotate-the-screen-89639.html

Comment: This could also be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode

Answer (score 5):

You can use `-webkit-transform`(CSS) property to change the orientation:

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $('body').css({
        "-webkit-transform": "rotate(90deg)"
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First make the body full screen. You can do it by

```
document.body.requestFullscreen().then(res=>console.log(res).catch(err=>console.log(err);
```

Then rotate it by using

```
screen.orientation.lock('landscape').then(res=>console.log(res)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Note :  This will work only in mobile browser. If you don't know how to use console in android chrome then please read this article [Here](https://dev.to/dev0x0/using-google-chrome-console-on-any-mobile-device-9ec)

Answer (score 1):

I think rotation in mobile requires an event listener to handle `screen.orientation.lock` error.

The `.main-app` is a body tag class.

In your HTML code add a button like:

```
    <div id="lock-landscape-btn" class="hidden">Lock</div>
    <div id="unlock-orientation" class="hidden">unLock</div>
```

In your JS code/file add an EventListener like:

```
    function rotateScreen () {

        document.querySelector('#lock-landscape-btn').addEventListener('click', function () {

            if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {

                if(document.querySelector(".main-app").requestFullscreen) {
                    document.querySelector(".main-app").requestFullscreen();
                }else if(document.querySelector(".main-app").webkitRequestFullScreen) {
                    document.querySelector(".main-app").webkitRequestFullScreen();
                }

                screen.orientation.lock("landscape-primary")
                    .then(function() {
                        console.log('landscape-primary');
                    })
                    .catch(function(error) {
                        console.log(error);
                    });
            }

        });

        document.querySelector("#unlock-orientation").addEventListener('click', function() {
            screen.orientation.unlock();
        });
    };
```