# How to force a mobile web page to load in landscape

Tags: javascript, css, mobile, viewport

We have a mobile web page on our website that needs to be always rendered in landscape in the browser when it's loaded. Also, the page needs to be locked in landscape, so that the device cannot change the orientation.

Is there any JS API in the major mobile browsers or CSS property that will accomplish this?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force “Landscape” orientation mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode)

Answer (score 4):

You can try using this code:

```
#container { display:block; }
@media only screen and (orientation:portrait){
  #container {
    height: 100vw;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
  #container {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
}
```

You should also add this to the body tag:

```
 <body id="container">
```

I found this solution [here](http://fuel-efficient-vehicles.org/pwsdb/?p=330). Same blog also offers additional suggestion but I didn't try them, as the above one worked well.

Comment: problem with `@media only screen and (orientation:landscape)` is that a browser ( at least FF) also applied to this rule ...