# Website Orientation

Tags: javascript, android, html, ios

I have a website which will be opened most time in mobile, and I need that website to be displayed in landscape mode by default. (Though user is in portrait mode, then also it should be in landscape mode).
Please help me out, which code to use...

I used this code but it didn't help me out, in any way..

```
<script>
  var start = function() {
    screen.orientation.lock('landscape-primary').then(
      startInternal,
      function() {
        alert('To start, rotate your screen to landscape.');

        var orientationChangeHandler = function() {
          if (!screen.orientation.type.startsWith('landscape')) {
            return;
          }
          screen.orientation.removeEventListener('change', orientationChangeHandler);
          startInternal();
        }

        screen.orientation.addEventListener('change', orientationChangeHandler);
      });
  }
  window.onload = start;
</script>
```

Comment: Are you using Webview for displaying website on your mobile??

Comment: I don't know how to use it, I am just using simple HTML as regular.

Comment: why dont you use css media queries? https://jsfiddle.net/5whzxb8m/

Answer (score 0):

might be easier if you used css ;

```
@media (orientation: portrait) { 
    .reorientMessage{
        visibility: visible;
    }
    .mainContent{
        visibility: hidden ;
    }
}
@media (orientation: landscape) { 
    .reorientMessage{
        visibility: hidden;
    }
    .mainContent{
        visibility: visible ;
    }
}
```

html eg.;

```
<div class="reorientMessage">please reorient etc..</div>
<div class="mainContent">normal stuff here</div>
```

Comment: It helped me out somewhere, but it forces the user to reorient. I need the website to be at landscaped only.

Comment: Looks like this may be what you want : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode

Comment: There may be other issues like whether the user's device/settings allows reorientation, whether the version of webkit on the device supports it without bugs etc. So answering your OP specifically - why THAT code isn't working for you is a bit difficult ( ie. how is it not working for you ? ) So I'll butt out here :)