# How to force a HTML5 game to load in landscape mode in Mobile browser?

Tags: html, html5-canvas, coronasdk, phaser-framework, mobile-browser

I am developing a 2D shooter game in landscape mode. When I view it in Desktop it is running fine. I want to give same experience in mobile too. Irrespective of the user's orientation.

Is it possible? If it is, how to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Force “Landscape” orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode)

Comment: Do use Corona (www.coronalabs.com) at all for developing a game?

Comment: @ldurniat :D yes.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is lock the possible orientations on the device. In order to do that you need to edit the settings on build.settings file, for example:

```
orientation =
{
    default = "landscapeRight",
    supported =
    {
        "landscapeRight", "landscapeLeft"
    }
}
```

Refer to the official docs [here](https://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/distribution/buildSettings/index.html) in the "App Orientation" section.