# Website in landscape mode on mobile device using angular?

Tags: html, css, angular

how is it possible to Website Automatically opens in landscape mode on mobile device using angular?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is an angular matter, but an HTML one. Maybe [this answer can help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14360699/5677252)

index.html

```
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
```

manifest.json

```
{
    "display":      "standalone", /* Could be "fullscreen", "standalone", "minimal-ui", or "browser" */
    "orientation":  "landscape", /* Could be "landscape" or "portrait" */
    ...
}
```