# Phaser3 how to start the game horizontally (mobile)

Tags: javascript, typescript, game-development, phaser-framework, phaserjs

I want to start my platform game that will run on mobile in Phaser3 horizontally, how do I do this. If I can't launch it directly horizontally, can I detect whether the user is holding the phone vertically or horizontally and show a warning?

Here is my config.ts class ;

```
import { Types } from "phaser";
import baseGameConfig from "@games/config.base";
import Scenes from "./src/scenes";
export const DEFAULT_WIDTH: number = 1280;
export const DEFAULT_HEIGHT: number = 720;
export const MAX_WIDTH: number = 1920;
export const MAX_HEIGHT: number = 1080;
export let SCALE_MODE: "FIT" | "SMOOTH" = "SMOOTH";

const gameConfig: Types.Core.GameConfig = {
  ...baseGameConfig,
  title: "monkeygo",
  scene: Scenes.BootScene.scene,
  physics: {
    default: "arcade",
    arcade: {
      debug: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
      gravity: {
        y: 1000,
      },
      fps: 30,
    },
  },
  scale: {
    mode: Phaser.Scale.NONE,
    autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
    width: DEFAULT_WIDTH,
    height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT,
  },
};

export default gameConfig;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Force “landscape” orientation mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14360581/force-landscape-orientation-mode)

Comment: you can show a warning with a css overlay `@media(orientation:portrait){.warning{display:block}}`

Answer (score 0):

You can set the orientation using the orientation property in the scale section of your game's config. To make the game run horizontally, set it to "landscape":

```
scale: {
  mode: Phaser.Scale.NONE,
  autoCenter: Phaser.Scale.CENTER_BOTH,
  width: DEFAULT_WIDTH,
  height: DEFAULT_HEIGHT,
  orientation: 'landscape', // Set the orientation to landscape
},
```

You can listen for the resize event to detect orientation changes and respond accordingly. For example, you can add the following code to your BootScene:

```
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'BootScene' });
  }

  preload() {
    this.load.image('warning', 'path/to/warning-image.png');
  }

  create() {
    this.scale.on('resize', this.handleResize, this);
    this.handleResize(); // Call it initially to set the correct orientation
  }

  handleResize() {
    if (this.scale.isGamePortrait) {
      // Show a warning message if the device is in portrait mode
      const warning = this.add.image(DEFAULT_WIDTH / 2, DEFAULT_HEIGHT / 2, 'warning');
      warning.setOrigin(0.5);
    }
  }
}
```

This code listens for the resize event and checks if the game is in portrait mode. If it is, it displays a warning message.

Hope this helps.